# Programmatically getting app XAML resource from MergedDictionaries

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1-universal

Universal Windows 8.1 Store Project here.

I need to programmatically get a resource from merged dictionaries of an application given a resource name.

I came up with a utility method which gets me what I want, but looks rather ugly to me:

```
public static async Task<T> GetAppResource<T>(string key) where T:class
{
  T resource = default(T);
  await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
    CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
    ()=>{
      foreach (var d in Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries) {
        foreach (var pair in d) {
          if (pair.Key.ToString() == key && pair.Value is T) {
            resource = pair.Value as T;
            goto End;
          }
        }
      }
      End:;
    }
  );
  return resource;
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

The dictionaries are declared as follows:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="..." />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="..." />
            ...
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Actually, I'm programmatically opening flyouts declared in the merged dictionaries.

Comment: "Better" how? It's not clear how you are declaring the dictionary, nor why you are accessing `MergedDictionaries` directly. Typically, one would just retrieve a value by key as usual, and let the `ResourceDictionary` object handle deferring the lookup to the merged dictionaries as necessary. I.e. just call `TryGetValue()`, or use the indexer syntax. Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're doing and why the usual mechanisms for value-by-key retrieval don't work for you.

Comment: Anyway, thank you, you did understand me, and you did answer my question, however easy it was. For some reason it did not occur to me yesterday, that all I needed to do was `Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue()`. Blunders happen. :) I can either delete the question or you may put the two sentences after 'Typically' into an answer and I accept it.

Comment: As there does not appear to be a similar question on SO already, and as it seems to me that the documentation is in fact less-than-clear on this point, I'll go ahead and post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dictionaries added to a `ResourceDictionary` via the `MergedDictionaries` property effectively become a part of the `ResourceDictionary` to which they are added. Retrieving a value from the top-level `ResourceDictionary` will involve searching for the value's key in the main dictionary, and if not found, traversing the `MergedDictionaries` to search for the key.

Thus, resources added via `MergedDictionaries` can be retrieved pretty much as though they are just contained in the top-level dictionary. The main difference being that duplicate keys are allowed in the merged dictionaries, with the value for a given key being retrieved from the *last* merged dictionary in which it's found, if not found in the top-level dictionary.

So you can call `TryGetValue()` on your top-level dictionary, use the indexer syntax (e.g. `Application.Current.Resources["someKey"]`), or even use an appropriate `FindResource()` call (i.e. depending on whether the context is an `Application` object or `FrameworkElement` object). The resource will be retrieved as if it were in the top-level dictionary itself.

I hope the above adequately elaborates on the documentation. The above is implied to some extent by the documentation in MSDN (e.g. [Merged Resource Dictionaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178(v=vs.100).aspx)), but they never really come right out and say so explicitly. :( The documentation focuses more on how to create merged dictionaries, rather than on how to actually use them once created.